# What is the difference between escaping and quoting spaces in path?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Here is my code:

```
cp "./somepath/somefile.ext" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

echo "fail here"
ls -l ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
echo "but success here"
ls -l "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/"
```

Why second ls returns `ls: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/: No such file or directory`,  when first one finds this dir?

Spent hours to debug this feature and can't understand the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ask [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
In yourscript line 6:
ls -l "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/"
       ^-- SC2088: Note that ~ does not expand in quotes.
```

It [goes on to explain](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2088) that to combine `~` and quotes, you can just leave the `~` outside:

```
ls -l ~/"Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Very little. `"a b"` is essentially identical to `\a\ \b`. The backslash escapes the following character; quotes escape every character with in the quotes. Most of the time, an escaped character evaluates to the same character (`\a` is the same as `a`, because `a` has no special meaning).

The error you see is because tilde expansion only applies to unquoted `~`. Your first `ls` should succeed, because `~` expands to your home directory. The second should fail because there is no directory literally named `~`.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on the command (read program) you're executing and how it handles the parameters you're passing.

This said, I would always prefer quotes when having to cope with spaces, as it's a more generic approach.

For instance, when using `scp`, you often would need to escape the second parameter twice, because it's escaped locally and then on the remote end:

```
scp ubuntu@localhost.com:"'a/b/My File a b c.xls'" .
scp ubuntu@localhost.com:a/b/My\\\ File\\\ a\\\ b\\\ c.xls .
```

As @that-other-guy said, careful to `~` expansion.

Comment: re: scp, better to have the shell do that quoting for you, as with `printf -v quoted_name %q "$name"; scp ubuntu@localhost.com:"$quoted_name" .`, rather than to encourage folks to do it themselves... doubly so in a script handling untrusted input.